# What are some good resources for learning about COM programming?

Tags: .net, com

I'm trying to learn more about COM, specifically .NET/COM Interop, but I've been unable to find many resources online. I'm wondering if there is some hidden cache of COM tutorials/examples somewhere.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Google was temporary switched off I guess...I provide a deeplink http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @rene: maybe not the .NET 1.1 version?

Comment: Ok, got the point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @rene I've looked at that, but compared to .NET documentation it seems sparse. I was hoping for some dark corner of the internet full of COM examples and tutorials.

Comment: @nathan It can get very dark in the COM world...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This book has been a valuable resource for me.
[.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide (2 Volume set)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232170X)

Answer (score 0):

If you got VS installed then the MSDN documentation is the best place to start with. They have everything from Getting started to different sorts of COM projects development examples.

And as far as the problems are concerned during development, you always have SO at your disposal